# CSS - control leading

Tags: css

How is the leading controlled in CSS? I have a heading tag that is wrapping. The distance between the top line and the bottom line is too much. I'd like to reduce that amount. It's not padding or margin as I've tried those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
line-height:normal;
```

or set it equal to your heading `font-size`.

Comment: The keyword `normal` denotes the initial value. Setting `line-height` to font size means setting the text solid, which may or may not be feasible, depending on content and font.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela  - yes - it resets to initial value - he probably had it set somewhere before in css (for example: bootstrap does this annoying thing to set it's own fixed line height to titles).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the leading is set with the `line-height` property, and for it, the best way is usually to set it as a pure number. It has the current font size as implied unit. Setting `line-height: 1` means setting text solid, so that the height of a line equals the size (height) of the font. For some fonts, you could use even smaller values like 0.9 or even 0.8. You need to test this with your actual content and styling, but it’s better to be cautious (the text might change some day, and the font used might not be what you declare).

Formatting of lines can be more complicated, though. If there are e.g. superscripts in the text or characters from different fonts, browser may feel forced to use a line height larger than declared in CSS.

P.S. As a rule, if a heading needs wrapping, it needs to be shortened.